# How to read incoming HEX values from Serial.read() method?

Tags: serial, esp32, string

***Brief description about the problem History***

Communicating with a old VersaStat II used GPIB port but the GPIB ports PCI card stopped working but there was a another port `25 pin rs232 Serial communication port` but even now, too bad computers are abending the Serial port luckily there is still `virtual Blutooth COM port` which can be used with a modern laptop so ***ESP32*** microcontroller was selected to communicate with this device wirelessly (might later go for HC05 module etc.).

***Fixing the voltage difference problem***

Now there is a big problem the esp32 Serial uses `+3.3 V` or logic `1` &  `0 V` for logic `0` But in the rs232 port logic `0` is `+3 V ~ +12 V` and logic `1` is `-3 V ~ -12 V`  also `± 3V`  undefined region. To overcome this problem I have used the following circuit with ***optocouplers***.

Here is the circuit diagram

[image]

The following code was used to communicate with the device easy as seems

Code

```
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
#endif

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
int speedsend = 9600;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(speedsend);
  Serial2.begin(speedsend);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32SERIAL");
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {

  if (Serial2.available()) {
//incoming data from the device
    int i = Serial2.read();
    SerialBT.write(i);
    Serial.println(i); // To check what is coming as output
  }
  if (SerialBT.available()) {
    Serial2.write(SerialBT.read());
  }

}
```

But I see no meaningful characters in putty (Bluetooth COM port) in Arduino Serial I see some numbers in HEX representation. Is this the way old devices communicate?

This link show how HEX numbers correlate with ASCII characters

https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html

How to fix this issue am I doing something wrong in here the circuit parameters etc.

***Communication Example with device***

For a start the `ID` command should give a number as 2532 according to book after the conversion it gives me 32 32 34 32 0 0 , 2242 looking at the Arduino Serial numbers with the help of the converting web site shown in above url. That's how I noticed It gives me HEX numbers.

Here is the PDF rs232c Interface section PDF the original Book came with ID command page too.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BHhIsloF4voMxoFeSlz1GsjwfgHwgsPJ/view?usp=sharing

Another book looks same but not from the book came with

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z0NUOe17SpVYTIBfEE8s0EKStfLKKv_-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: [This](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=103418.0) might help you

Comment: your question is unrelated to the arduino ... it is a general programming question

Comment: your problem is not hex to ascii coversion ... it is hex text to decimal coversion

Comment: Device transmits HEX values like in table

Comment: @Avon97 If you can provide a link for the manual of the device, we could check ourselves, what exactly gets send. In a short google search I only found manuals for version 3 or 4, but not for 2.

Comment: @chrisl I have full edited the question now

Comment: ` in Arduino Serial I see some numbers in HEX representation.` -- No you don't. You're using `println()` on an integer which gives a decimal representation. To get HEX you have to specifically request a HEX representation. Your numbers are decimal. 32 is a space.

Comment: You have miss understand @Majenko the Arduino Serial is used see What is coming to ```i``` variable because in putty Bluetooth Serial has no meaningful result and you are correct 32 is space I see that in Bluetooth Serial in putty it goes like ```__"_ ``` as I remember. ( underscore is a space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you don't need that really complex optocoupler circuit. You just need a run-of-the-mill MAX3232 chip (note the extra 3 in there: it's the 3.3V version), that's what they're designed for: RS232 to 3.3V logic level conversion. You can pick up breakout modules for pennies on your favourite marketplace (ali-express, ebay, etc).

As for your reading, your assumption that your numbers are hexadecimal is completely wrong. They're decimal, not hexadecimal.

You read the data from the remote device and store each byte in an integer variable. Then you print that integer variable using `Serial.println()`. That will always give you a decimal representation of the numeric integer variable.

Your response of `32 32 34 32 0 0 , 2242` to my trained eye looks like bad communication. Maybe caused by your optocoupler circuit (change that for a MAX3232 immediately), or maybe caused by a mismatch in your baud rate, bit count, or parity settings.

Comment: Thank you, I have to check the communication first with my old core 2 duo computer first, it has a built in Serial port Yeah you may be right it has do something with communication error

Comment: Indeed it was bad communication error I did connect it to the computer (COM port) directly now it works fine

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is, that you try to provide a HEX value, but you are actually providing a decimal value.

When you just write a whole number like `32`, it will be interpreted by the compiler as a decimal number. The decimal number `32` is equal to HEX `20`, which is a space character in ASCII.

**Solution:** Write your number as decimal value like this:

```
int i = 0x32;
```

The `0x` preceding the value will mark it as a hexadecimal representation.

Comment: But I get 32 from the method ```int i = Serial2.read();``` if i is 32 how to fix this

Comment: Are you getting a byte with the decimal value 32, or are you receiving ASCII encoded hex data (That would be 2 characters, one `'3'` and one `'2'`)? If the device send the decimal value 32 in one byte, why would it mean hexadecimal 32 with that? So what exactly are you receiving?

Comment: I am receiving value 2 gets as 32 to int i

Comment: You didn't really answer my question. Are you receiving the ASCII character `'2'`? How exactly did you check, that `i` is 32 (hex or decimal?) for you?

Comment: When I send the ID command from putty I get values 32 32 34 32 0 0 in `read()` method 
one by one for variable ```i``` when I convert it is 2 2 4 2 or 2242 book says I should get something like  2532 representing the VersaStat 2 TM with Arduinos int to ascii conversion this has no meaning at all. Also if I send wrong commands a error light turns on in the device it turns off after I send a correct command. That's how I though this has to be character 2 for 32

Comment: How is Putty involved?  Can you show more of your code?  If 32 -> '2' then it looks like you are looking for a decimal to ASCII conversion.  A hex to ASCII conversion of 0x32 would get you ' '.

Comment: @DaveX its something like this ```if (Serial2.available()) {
int i = Serial2.read();
Serial.println(i);
}```

Comment: You could use `Serial.println(i,DEC);`, `Serial.println(i,HEX);` or `Serial.write(i);Serial.println();` to echo what you receive on Serial2 out on Serial in different formats.